# How to create a list of tibbles (from xlsx files) in R without losing data?

Tags: r, list, tibble, readxl

I need to read some capricious xlsx files in R. Converting them to csv messes up the column names, so I'm forced to use an alternative. I can read my files with the library readxl and the function read_xlsx().

My idea was to loop on each file to read to validate them and put them in a list. Then looping on each element of the list and do the work for each file.

However, read_xlsx() ouput is a tibble. I don't know anything about them, but they don't seem to appreciate being put in and extracted from a list.

For example, I use an excel file like this

| this | is | a | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

With a code like this:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "../Data")
dataList <- list()

for (filename in filenames) {
  filepath <- paste0("../Data/", filename)
  data <- read_xlsx(filepath)
  print(data)
  dataList[filename] <- data
  print(dataList)
}
```

The output will be

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
   this    is     a  test
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3     4
2     5     6     7     8

[[1]]
[1] 1 5
```

Why did I lose so much data? Is there any way to create a list of tibbles in order to manipulate each element of the list later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For access a list item you need `[[` not `[`.

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "../Data")
dataList <- list()

for (filename in filenames) {
  filepath <- paste0("../Data/", filename)
  data <- read_xlsx(filepath)
  dataList[[filename]] <- data
}
```

Another way to achieve this is `foreach` package which would return a list.

```
library(foreach)

dataList <- foreach(filename = filenames, 
                    .final = function(x) { setNames(x, filenames) }) %do% {
  filepath <- paste0("../Data/", filename)
  data <- read_xlsx(filepath)
  data
}
```

Comment: Oh, I just spent more than an hour on this and this was so simple... Thank you so much!